# Why does objects.create() fail silently?

Tags: django, django-models

When I create an object via `[model].objects.create()` and I set one of the field variables incorrectly, the create will fail. However it even with `debug=True` it does not produce an exception.

E.g. the following fails silently:

```
Email(models.Model):
   email = models.EmailField()

details = {'email': '1234'} # Fails because it is not a valid EmailField
Email.objects.create(**details)
```

Why is this, and when I have a large model with lots of fields how can I debug which field is failing?

Comment: It does not fail silently. Validations do *not* run when creating, or `.save()`ing a model object, because of performance reasons. You can raise `obj.full_clean()`. Furthermore a `ModelForm` will do that too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does *not* fail silently. Validations do *not* run when creating, or `.save()`ing a model object, because of performance reasons. You can raise [**`.full_clean()`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.full_clean). This is specified in the [*Validating objects* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/instances/#validating-objects):

> Note that **`full_clean()` will not be called automatically when you call your model’s `save()` method**. You’ll need to call it manually when you want to run one-step model validation for your own manually created models.

One therefore usually uses a [**`ModelForm`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/modelforms/) that will perform validation by calling the cleaning functions. These therefore act as a validation layer between the user and the models.